# i want to remove x of list but telll that:x is not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to find the minimum member of list and remove that from list and append to another list but after i find that in a loop,it does not remove and tell that:x not in list

```
l=[2,5,6,1,8,9]
g=10
a=[]
for i in l:
    if i<g:
        g=i
a.append(g)
print(g)
l.remove(g)



output is:
g=1
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

after i can not remove member,i try to remove it by pop(),first i find the index number bye a loop and try to remove it by pop(),but tell:pop index is out of range.

```
l=[2,4,5,1,4]
g=10
h=m=0
a=[]
while(h<len(l)):
    h=h+1
    for i in l:
        if i<g:
            g=i
    a.append(g)
    for n in l:
        if n!=g:
            m=m+1
        if n==g:
            break
    print(m)
    l.pop(m)
out put is:
3
7
IndexError: pop index out of range
eventhough:l[3]=1
```

Comment: `l.remove(l)` - removing the list from itself?? And why not just `l.remove(min(l))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the list from the list using the statement `l.remove(l)`, you should instead use `l.remove(g)`.

Python also has a built in minimum function `min()`.

For your second example do not mutate a list while iterating through it.

Code:

```py
l = [1,2,3,9,12,5]

print(l)

l.remove(min(l))

print(l)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 5]
[2, 3, 9, 12, 5]
```

Comment: your code is best and correct but i want to write a code to find min of list and do not using:min().

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to your code, I supose this is the correct indentation for it to work. It will store the minimum value in a list.

```
l=[2,5,6,1,8,9]
g=10
a=[]
    for i in l:
        if i<g:
            g=i
            a.append(g)
c=a.pop()
```

Since the lowest value of the array is the last to be appended it is popped and stored in c.

```
l.remove(c)
```

This will remove the primitive lowest value (1 in this case)

Comment: But, of course, using min() as pointed by @Jmonsky will be the best solution since you won't have to set a variable g with a value higher than any in your array.

Comment: this code has a error that the first element of list is 2 and it is lower than 10 so:append to another list.but the lowest member of list is 1.

Comment: This code is based on your code, which appended  the lowest value to the list (by resetting the value of g in every interaction). If you run this code as it goes through the list "l" it will first append "2" to "a" and set "g" to "2" looking now for a value lesser than "2" it will only append to "a" when i=1 and that's where it ends, with a=[2,1] since the last value is always the smallest c=a.pop() will return one and l.remove(c) would just remove 1 from the list.

Comment: @sajjjadghasemi as I've read above you don't want to use min() you could set "g" first using max() and use the iteration that I've proposed, that way you won't have to know the values of every list to set "g" above them in order to remove the smallest.

Comment: in the code that i use,i know that all of members of list is under 10,i mean these are just from 1 to 9.and i want to find min of them every time and append it to another list and remove from this list to set a list that start with min to max number between 1:9.

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer.i have to reinitialize g.and now we can use this code in loop.

```
l=[2,5,6,1,8,9]
g=10
a=[]
for i in l:
    if i<g:
        g=i
a.append(g)
l.remove(g)
g=10
```

in this code:in loop,code compare the elements with g again.
source:[ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662899/valueerror-list-removex-x-not-in-list-python)